# Backup and replace MySQL database each day for speed

Tags: mysql

I was thinking of making a GPS tracking app that stores clients GPS coordinates every second in a MySQL database. I would have one row per GPS entry (lat,lon, speed, time, elevation, user id, item_id, etc) each second for each user.

My calculation is that it could take up to 3 or 5 meg of MySQL space per day for each user to store all their GPS data.

I dont know how MySQL works, but im assuming it would certainly slow down if i have thousands of users running this poor database into the ground each day, and the size would reach tera bytes.

So i thought each day to back up the whole database, delete it and start a new data base each day. So this would create a bunch of smaller databases that may be better than having one extremely large database whose size would keep growing forever.

But then im wondering about duplicate IDs in the databases may be a problem, when a new database is created, all the id would start over creating a conflict with all the previous ids in the other databases.

Anybody knows how the big boys do this kind of thing? Im sure they dont have one incredibly large database with everything in there that keeps growing by terabytes each day. Does database access slow down when the size grows larger and larger? I dont know how it works really

Thanks

Comment: Have you thought about using a NoSQL data store, e.g. Cassandra?  This would be a good option if you need to write large amounts of data, quickly, but you only would have an occasional need to query this data.

Comment: I never heard of it, i will definitely check it out, awesome comment, thanks!!!

Comment: One issue here is how much data you really have every day.  If it's in the GB or TB, then relational SQL probably won't scale well, at least not at a cost which won't make your eyes pop out.

Comment: good to know good to know, will definitely switch to the NO SQL if i can get a open source one from somewhere like mySQL type deal. Thanks!